# Passing multiple arguments to C program

Tags: c, command-line

I've wrote a small C program, which takes 3 integers as arguments. If I am running it like this:  `myapp 1 2 3` runs fine, `argc` shows correctly 4, but if I do: `echo 1 2 3 | myapp`, argc shows just 1.

The relevant part of the C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
printf("Entered: %i\n", argc);
if ( argc < 4)
{
printf("You must enter 3 integers as command line arguments!\n");
exit(1);
}
}
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe passes the output of the first process to the `stdin` of the second process, which has nothing to do with command-line arguments. What you want is `xargs`, which uses the output of the first process and uses it as command line arguments:

```
echo 1 2 3 | xargs myapp
```

Comment: Yep, I am tired, I've forgot the xargs... Thanks! :) I will accept you r answer asap.

Answer (score 4):

`echo 1 2 3 | myapp` calls `myapp` with no arguments. Values are passed through `stdin`.

You may want to use this instead (if using bash in Unix):

```
    myapp `echo 1 2 3`
```

Or, if you have a list of numbers in a file called numbers.txt, you can do this as well:

```
    myapp `cat numbers.txt`
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo 1 2 3 | myapp` will send 1 2 3 to the standard input of your program. If your program does not read from it, it will never see those numbers. You need to use for instance [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for this to work. Note that you will have to parse the string by yourself to count the number of 'arguments' passed this way.